# Who first used the term "spirit of fornication" ( )?

Tags: church-fathers, apostolic-fathers, pre-nicene-fathers

Who first used the term "spirit of fornication" (*spiritus fornicationis*)?

It appears in the [Litany of the Saints (*Litaniæ Sanctorum*)](https://www.preces-latinae.org/thesaurus/Sancti/LitSanctorum.html):

> A spiritu fornicationis,
> ℟. libera nos, Domine.
> <sub>From the spirit of fornication,
>
> ℟. deliver us, O Lord.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching the [*Patrologia Latina* database](https://pld.chadwyck.com/all/search), St. Ambrose seems to be the first Latin Father who uses the term, in [his commentary](https://pld.chadwyck.com/all/fulltext?action=byid&id=Z400141322) on [Psalm 118:153](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=21&ch=118&l=153-#x)-160 (Hebrew letter "Resh", ר), Sermon 20, [*PL* 15](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6912) col. 1575:

> 45. […] Unde et Apostolus ait: *Fugite fornicationem* ([I Cor. VI, 18](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=53&ch=6&l=18-#x)). Nam qua causa fugeres, nisi illa te persequeretur? Est enim malus spiritus fornicationis, est malus spiritus avaritiæ, malus spiritus superbiæ.
>     <sub>Wherefore the Apostle also said: *Flee fornication* ([1 Cor. 6:18](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=53&ch=6&l=18-#x)). For what reason would you flee unless it pursued you? For there is an evil spirit of fornication, there is an evil spirit of covetousness, an evil spirit of pride.</sub>

> 47. […] Tentatus es spiritu fornicationis; sed veritus Christi futurum judicium, temerandam mentis et corporis castimoniam non putasti: martyr es Christi. […]
>     <sub>You were tempted by the spirit of fornication; but, fearing the future judgment of Christ, did not consider the chastity of mind and body to be violated: you are a martyr of Christ.</sub>